# Shouldn't have vs. Shouldn't of

Tags: contractions

Got into an argument with someone I know about this. I think "shouldn't of" is incorrect and comes from people typing the phrase the way they're used to pronouncing it.

He believes both are correct. Thoughts guys?

Comment: Voting to close on the grounds this is a constant source of peeving amongst English-speaking people at large. So if OP really needs confirmation of his position there's a whole internet out there full of it.

Comment: Fumble, I did search. I found no great consensus. Are you telling me that there is not an acceptable answer?

Comment: Dang it. :( Fml.

Comment: @hmedia1: Using ***of*** instead of ***have*** in the specified context is an appalling grammatical error, that's ***easily*** identified by simply typing ***should of*** into a Google search box. Hardly the sort of trivia that needs to be addressed by a site aimed at [linguists, etymologists, and (serious) English language enthusiasts.](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very right, Daniel. The correct phrase is "shouldn't have", but because in speech, we tend to pronounce the "'ve" part of "have" only, it could be mistaken for "of". See this [site:](http://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/couldof.html)

> This is one of those errors typically made by a person more familiar with the spoken than the written form of English. A sentence like “I would have gone if anyone had given me free tickets” is normally spoken in a slurred way so that the two words “would have” are not distinctly separated, but blended together into what is properly rendered “would’ve.” Seeing that “V” tips you off right away that “would’ve” is a contraction of “would have.” But many people hear “would of” and that’s how they write it. Wrong.

Now, I know the above article is talking about "should of" not "shouldn't of", but where does "shouldn't of" come from? It's a negation of the root mistake!

Comment: I have seen "sould of", "would of", "could of". HUGE peeve of mine! It ranks right up there with "knowed" in my peeve level! "You should of knowed it was gonna happen!"

Answer (score 2):

"Shouldn't've" is a double contraction of "should not" and "shouldn't have."  "Shouldn't of" is not correct.

http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_double_contractions